# Choosing between multiple executables with same name in Linux

Tags: linux, path

The system I am using has `gnuplot` installed in `/usr/bin`. I don't have root, but I needed a newer version of `gnuplot`, so I installed it to `$HOME/usr/bin`.

I added `$HOME/usr/bin` to my path, but it still executes the one in `/usr/bin` if I just use the gnuplot command. I'd rather not have to specify `$HOME/usr/bin/gnuplot` every time I have to use it.

How do I tell Linux to use the one in my home directory, and not the one in `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Executables are found in PATH order. You need to prepend `${HOME}/usr/bin` to your path, like so:

```
export PATH="${HOME}/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Just curious, is this applicable for other OSs as well ?

Answer (score 24):

Executables are found in PATH order. Your PATH apparently is set up such that `/usr/bin` precedes `~/usr/bin/`.

Comment: It would be better if you supply some docs to support your standpoint.

Answer (score 10):

Besides modifying the PATH as has been explained, you can also use aliases like this (in BASH)

```
alias gn=$HOME/usr/bin/gnuplot
```

then you just run it with

```
gn
```

Comment: Not so sure hard coding a path is a good idea for an alias. I  would rather use it to specify flags that I always wanted.

Comment: In this case, where you want a specific version of a program, I see no problem at all.

Comment: This one is really useful

Answer (score 4):

What Bombe says is ok. I would add that you should declare your user specific PATH entries inside your user's bashrc (`$HOME/.bashrc`), so your PATH settings only apply to your user.

Comment: He doesn't have root, so I doubt he could globally change the PATH :)

Comment: Please re-read my answer. I state that he should change his own user's .bashrc, which is of course writable by the own user (who in fact is the owner of the file).