# how to use cmake that installed in a non-standard path?

Tags: compilation, cmake, environment-variables

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.3 platform. While I was compiling a project it asked cmake version 3.2 which is not present in my system. I compiled the latest version of cmake from source code and installed it into /usr/local/bin directory. When I attempt to compile project again, its cmake detects the cmake in /usr/bin which is lower version. Then `cmake ..`

process aborts with lower version error. Is there any built-in cmake variable or environment variable for setting path of the cmake?

EDIT: 
I just found a cmake variable [CMAKE_COMMAND](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_COMMAND.html) that supposedly does what I want. 
But when I insert `CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/local/bin/cmake` line into cmakelist.txt then I go to `build` directory and issue `/usr/local/bin/cmake ..` 
I get :

```
  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text
```

I searched for it on the net but didn't find a solution.

Comment: It is path-resolution process who responsible for choose cmake executable. So you should affect on that process. E.g, swap /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin in PATH, or use full path when invoke: `/usr/local/bin/cmake`,

Comment: @Tsyvarev
Thank you for responding. How can I swap the paths? I already tried with `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:"$PATH"` no luck.

Comment: Try that: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` (found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/413498/3440745).

Comment: @Tsyvarev
Thank you bro, it works ( once I read about that double quotation mark fix, but I forgot it)  but I get another error message related to different issue. I will let you know when I achieve the compilation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have different versions of a software or library installed you may use `stow` to install and switch between the two. Especially if you want to install a newer version of a software that is not available in one's Linux distribution. So in case the new version is not yet stable you can still switch to the previous one. For example while building cmake 3.2 you can specify the prefix as

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/stow/cmake-3.2/
```

and then

```
cd /usr/local/stow
sudo stow cmake-3.2
```

and if you want to remove the links you can use the following command

```
sudo stow --delete cmake-3.2
```

Please keep in mind stow does not delete files. It only makes and deletes links.