# How to make builds use the newer version of two installed OpenCVs?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I have just installed the newest OpenCV from source. After the installation I found that OpenCV was already installed on my computer. Now I have a `/usr/include/opencv` and a `/usr/include/opencv2` existing together.

When I was trying to compile an example from the newest version, it automatically went to the directory `opencv2` to find the header files. Obviously some examples in the new version require header files that only exist in `opencv` but not in `opencv2`.

I checked the version being used as follows.

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
2.4.8
```

How can I clean the old version and set the environmental variables such that the newer version is used instead?

---

Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't realize that both `/opencv` and `/opencv2` exist at the same time in normal installations. So these folders are irrelevant.

Here's what I did to install OpenCV. I followed this tutorial on my newly installed ubuntu 14.04:
http://www.bogotobogo.com/OpenCV/opencv_3_tutorial_ubuntu14_install_cmake.php

I git cloned and did a full make install. I thought the git source was of version 3.0.0, am I wrong on that?

(Sorry for the late edit and thanks so much for your help!!)

Comment: I've been using apt-get. I'm not sure to remove the old version directly, will the dependencies and other settings mess up if I do so?

Comment: Not sure if you realise that it is normal to have both `opencv` and `opencv2` in a single OpenCV installation.

Comment: Please state in detail _how_ you did install OpenCV from source (cmake, make, sudo make install?). Please also tell us whether you have installed the packages `libcv-dev` or `libopencv-dev`.

Comment: If you want to have different versions of a software or library installed you may use stow. I have explained have a way to use it in the following answer: http://goo.gl/97H8xE

Comment: Here is the full link, I can not edit my earlier post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828980/how-to-use-cmake-that-installed-in-a-non-standard-path/32840638#32840638

Comment: `opencv2` may be referring to the modernized C++ OpenCV includes, whereas the `opencv` contains the older C-callable OpenCV includes. [All versions of OpenCV since 2.0.0 have those two folders](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/include). Despite you finding *some examples in the new version*, I suspect that the code in your examples may have contained obsolete code that hasn't been updated for a decade or so. You can check for the OpenCV version by [writing a simple program and printing out its version string](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=check+opencv+version).

Comment: You can look into this file to check the version of your git clone: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp

Answer (score 3):

To reproduce your problem, I have just installed OpenCV from the Ubuntu package repository:

```
$ sudo aptitude install libopencv-dev
```

Which put include files to these places:

```
/usr/include/opencv
/usr/include/opencv2
```

I then downloaded and installed OpenCV from this place: http://opencv.org/

```
$ cd Downloads/opencv-3.0.0
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
[lots of configuration related output ...]
$ make -j7
[lots of build related output ...]
$ sudo make install
[lots of installation related output ...]
```

pkg-config now finds the newer version:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.0.0
```

And the includes are located here:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv
/usr/local/include/opencv2
```

You shouldn't have a problem, given you want to use the later installed version. (Are you sure you did properly install the custom build: `sudo make install`?)

---

You might want to remove the older version:

```
$ sudo aptitude remove libopencv-dev
```

However, you should make sure that you don't remove dependencies your custom build relies on (zlib, libjpeg, libtiff, pibpng, ...).

---

That being said, pkg-config gives you the details from the opencv.pc file it finds last.

These are the available files:

```
$ locate opencv.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
```

The latter belongs to the newer version (build from source), the first belongs to the older version (package install).

This is the search path:

```
$ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

Given this order of the entries in the search path, you get the newer version via pkg-config.